# Problemas al formatear un String en fecha

Tags: javascript, string, date

Mi problema radica en que yo recibo de mi formulario un elemento String, que puede ser de estos dos formatos:

```
fecha = "010117";
```

o

```
fecha = "01012017";
```

Y necesito formatearlos a un formato de fecha válido como `"01/01/2017"`, he probado a hacerlo de varias maneras, entre ellas esta:

```
var newfecha = new Date( fecha.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
```

Pero no lo realiza correctamente, alguien podria darme alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tienes que dar más información. ¿Ese parámetro lo recibes en Java y quieres tratar la fecha desde Java o desde Javascript?¿ Quieres usar expresiones regulares o cualquier método vale?

Comment: Yo tengo un formulario de Java con un elemento de entrada de fecha, donde recojo un tipo DATE, el problema es que si yo, en lugar de recogerlo mediante el calendario desplegable que se abre, o mediante un formato correcto de fecha, tipo "01/01/2017" lo recojo asi "01012017" no tengo manera de operar con el.

Comment: ¿No puedes cambiar el tipo Date de java a String y usar la solución de Juanjo o similar? Tienes que modificar el dato desde Javascript?

Comment: Estoy operando en el formulario con un ace:dateTimeEntry, componente de icefaces, y por algun motivo, sino sleccionaba un dia del calendario, o con el formato correcto dd/mm/yyyy se quedaba bloqueado... Al final pude arreglado con la sugerencia de PbxMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo en javascript por si te sirve de ayuda.

```
alert(checkDate('010117'));
alert(checkDate('01012017'));

function checkDate(myFecha){
    var ret = "error";
    //pasa la expresion regular
    var m = myFecha.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2,4})$/);
    if(m==null){
        alert('la fecha no es valida');
    } else {
        //si vienen sólo 2 digitos en año asumo que es el año 2000
        if(m[3].length==2){
            m[3] = '20' + m[3];
        }
        try {
            //usa la funcion toISOString para comprobar que la fecha es válida
            new Date(m[3] + '-' + m[2] + '-' + m[1]).toISOString();     
            ret = m[1] + '-' + m[2] + '-' + m[3];
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert('la fecha no es valida');
        }   
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Gecias por la ayuda, asi solucione el problema, despues vastó son sustituir el valor retornado de nuevo enel formulario y listo. Mil Gracias ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar un SimpleDataFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato;  
    if(fecha.length==6)
        formato = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyy");
    else
        formato = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");

        try {
            Date date = formato.parse(fecha);
             System.out.println(date);
             //Fecha con formato dd-MM-yyyy
             System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            //
        }
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta línea:

```
fecha.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d+)/, function(s, d, m, a){ 
    return [d, m, a.length === 2 ? "20" + a : a].join("/")
});
```

El propósito es separar los (4 o 2) *(\d+)* últimos números, luego anteponemos `20` si en caso este tiene 2 dígitos.

```js
//var fecha = "01012017";
var fecha = "010117";

var newFecha = fecha.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d+)/, function(s, d, m, a){ 
 return [d, m, a.length === 2 ? "20" + a : a].join("/")
});

console.log(newFecha); //01/01/2017
```